# Auto delete Rabbit MQ queues after x period of time

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, rabbitmq-exchange, erlang-shell

is there any option to auto delete Rabbit MQ queues after x period of time in RabbitMQ console as it is using a lot of space in Windows server 2016 (in my case it took more than 15GB of disk space for more than 400 queues)

C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\db\rabbit@{machine_name}-mnesia\vhosts{Random_number}\queues\

is there any way to delete these queues without stopping rabbitmq service.

More details:

OS : Windows server 2016

Rabbit MQ version : 3.7.9

Erlang version : 10.0.1

For now we are deleting the folders after stopping the service. any suggestions to automate it